# Devise treating update as delete when editing User name or password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

So I'm having an issue when the user is trying to update his password/avatar/name.

The problem lies in Devise model registration.

In `myapp/views/users/registrations/edit.html.erb`:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put, class: 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>     <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :avatar, class: 'col-sm-2 control-label'  %>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :name, class: 'col-sm-2 control-label'%>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        <%= f.text_field :name, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control'%>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :email, class: 'col-sm-2 control-label'  %>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control'  %>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :password, class: 'col-sm-2 control-label'  %> <i>(leave blank if you don't want to change it)</i>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", class: 'form-control'  %>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :password_confirmation, class: 'col-sm-2 control-label' %>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off", class: 'form-control'  %>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :current_password, class: 'col-sm-2 control-label' %> 
         <i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <%= f.password_field :current_password, autocomplete: "off", class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6">
            <%= f.submit "Update", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        </div>
    </div>
<hr>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6">
           `Unhappy?`                                         
    <%= button_to "Cancel my account", registration_path(resource_name), data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-default btn-xs' %>
     <%= link_to "Back", :back %>

        </div>
    </div><% end %>
```

And my development Log is

```
Started DELETE "/users" for 128.224.252.2 at 2017-06-21 17:21:26 +0000 Cannot render console from 128.224.252.2! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255 Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#destroy as HTML Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"RBkvQWXmVVY5rHEa7t0yh41QmMDS4HBcPCLJkKZ0RQYkpFfPXc7ebF6u3YKuF1BiOs5RDng3cFIWTFoZPmhLAw==", "user"=>{"name"=>"adnan", "email"=>"adhajar.work@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "current_password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Update"} User Load (2.9ms) SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1 [["id", 104]]  (0.2ms) BEGIN SQL (0.3ms) DELETE FROM "users_roles" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1 [["user_id", 104]] SQL (0.4ms) DELETE FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 [["id", 104]]  (3.0ms) COMMIT Redirected to https://confessionbox-adnanhajar.c9users.io/ Completed 302 Found in 47ms (ActiveRecord: 6.7ms)

Started GET "/" for 128.224.252.2 at 2017-06-21 17:21:26 +0000 Cannot render console from 128.224.252.2! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255 Processing by PagesController#index as HTML Rendered pages/index.html.erb within layouts/application (68.0ms) Completed 200 OK in 74ms (Views: 72.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 128.224.252.2 at 2017-06-21 17:43:01 +0000 Cannot render console from 128.224.252.2! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255 Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML Rendered users/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (81.2ms) Completed 200 OK in 90ms (Views: 87.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Started GET "/users/auth/facebook" for 128.224.252.2 at 2017-06-21 17:43:03 +0000 Cannot render console from 128.224.252.2! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255`
```

Any idea why this is happening ?

Thank you prior!

Comment: what happens when you just do `<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, html: { class: 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>`

Comment: This what I get: Routing Error No route matches [DELETE] "/users/106" Rails.root: /home/ubuntu/workspace Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace Routes Routes match in priority from top to bottom. Somehow it's interpreting it as a delete request –